# Windows 10: How to find what font is used by a certain program

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts

I have a commercial software running on my Windows 10 machine and somehow, someday, I've installed/overwritten a few fonts and now the software displays some weird chars instead of plain ASCII text.

For example "This is a test phrase" looks like this: 
[image: This is a test phrase]

I tried resetting/restoring Windows fonts by using the **restore default font settings**, but nothing changed.

Installing the same software on similar configuration displays the font correctly and the developer doesn't have a solution to this problem, mainly because it's an isolated issue that's only happening on my computer. The only way to use this software on my computer would be to do a fresh reinstall but there has to be a better way.

Originally posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379376/windows-how-to-find-what-font-is-used-by-a-certain-program

Comment: That is [Wingdings 1](https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/wingdings/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How can I find what fonts are used by a certain program?

You can use [ProcessActivityView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/process_activity_view.html) from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/):

> ProcessActivityView creates a summary of all files and folders that
> the selected process tries to access. For each file that the process
> access, the following information is displayed: Number of times that
> the file was opened and closed, number of read/write calls, total
> number of read/write bytes, the dll that made the last open-file call,
> and more...
>
> [image]

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: Also, with Sysinternals tools process monitor and process explorer.

Comment: You are right @DavidPostill, having the above-mentioned software monitoring my application and while I tried to change font-related settings I was able to identify the font used and successfully managed to re-install it. Now I can properly use my software, so thumbs up from me.